# Update div class based on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is borrowed from another question I made on the site, but would have got really messy.

So using some of the code from one of the repliers, how do I get this code to work... or have I got it completely wrong.

Select Options are:

```
<select style="width: 220px; display: none;" id="speedB" name="category">
    <option value=""<?if ($category == ""){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Please Select</option>
    <option value="1"<?if ($category == "1"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Pest Inspectors</option>
    <option value="3"<?if ($category == "3"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Building Inspectors</option>
    <option value="2"<?if ($category == "2"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Removalists</option>
    <option value="5"<?if ($category == "5"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Conveyancing</option>
    <option value="4"<?if ($category == "4"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Pool Inspectors</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#speedB').change(function() {
                      var myTypes = {
                        '': '.nothing',
                        '1': '.pest',
                        '2': '.build',
                        '3': '.removals',
                        '4': '.legal',
                        '5': '.pool'
                      }
                      var selectedType = myTypes[$(this).val()];
                      $('#topright').html('<div class="'+selectedType+'"/></div>');
                    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="topright"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#topright {
height: 70px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
width: 70px;
}
.pest {
background: url("images/pestcorner.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.build {
background: url("images/buildcorner.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.removals {
background: url("images/removalscorner.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.legal {
background: url("images/legalcorner.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.pool {
background: url("images/poolcorner.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Essentially, I want user to select from select box, and that invokes display of the css class.

I think I have screwed the js up.

Comment: Bloody done it, I added .pest instead of pest !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'd do it like this:

First, add HTML data attributes with the corresponding class name for each option:

```
<select style="width: 220px; display: none;" id="speedB" name="category">
    <option data-class="nothing" value=""<?if ($category == ""){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Please Select</option>
    <option data-class="pest" value="1"<?if ($category == "1"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Pest Inspectors</option>
    <option data-class="build" value="3"<?if ($category == "3"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Building Inspectors</option>
    <option data-class="removals" value="2"<?if ($category == "2"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Removalists</option>
    <option data-class="legal" value="5"<?if ($category == "5"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Conveyancing</option>
    <option data-class="pool" value="4"<?if ($category == "4"){?> selected="selected"<?}?>>Pool Inspectors</option>
</select>
```

This way the relationships between CSS class and selected option are nicely prominent.
You can then do:

```
$('#speedB').change(function() {
    $('#topright').html('<div class="'+$(this).find(":selected").data("class")+'"/></div>');
});
```

Apart from that, you got the solution yourself (extra "." in the name of the class being added).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this really easily using a JS framework like Mootools. In Mootools, all you'd have to do is something like `selectBox.addEvent('selected', function(target) { target.swapStyle(newStyle); } );`.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it's working. The problem is not in the code, but there is a programming logic problem.

To fix this logic problem, I think the only thing you need to do is to change the "myType" array from this:

```
var myTypes = {
    '': '.nothing',
    '1': '.pest',
    '2': '.build',
    '3': '.removals',
    '4': '.legal',
    '5': '.pool' }
```

To this:

```
var myTypes = {
    '': '.nothing',
    '1': 'pest',
    '2': 'build',
    '3': 'removals',
    '4': 'legal',
    '5': 'pool'
}
```

Since it's gonna be a value for "class" attribute, you don't need the DOT before the class name.